# Custom view onConfigurationChanged not called when overriding onAttachBaseContext

Tags: android, setlocale

I am overriding `onAttachBaseContext()`in my `Activity`to pass the latest locale. But after doing this , I observed my custom view in Activity class no longer gets a call to `onConfigurationChanged()` on orienation change. Only the `Activity` `onConfigurationChanged()` gets the call. Is there a way to correct this? (I don't want to pass the event from `Activity` to custom view for orientation change)

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.setLanguage(newBase));
}
```

LocaleHelper:

```
public class LocaleHelper extends ContextWrapper {

public LocaleHelper(Context base) {
    super(base);
}

public static Context setLanguage(Context context) {
    String currentLanguage = getLanguage(context);
    context = setLocale(context, currentLanguage);
    return new LocaleHelper(context);
}

public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
    persist(context, language);
    return updateResources(context, language);
}


private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    Logger.log(TAG, "persist: "+language);
    editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
    editor.apply();
}

private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Logger.log(TAG, "updateResources: "+language);

    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
    if (isAtleastNougat()) {
        config.setLocale(locale);
        LocaleList localeList = new LocaleList(locale);
        LocaleList.setDefault(localeList);
        config.setLocales(localeList);
        context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
    }
    else if (isAtleastAPI17()) {
        config.setLocale(locale);
        context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
    } else {
        config.locale = locale;
        resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    return context;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Dont use updateResources function. Replace with function in this class:

```
public class MyContextWrapper extends ContextWrapper {

    public MyContextWrapper(Context base) {
        super(base);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static ContextWrapper wrap(Context context, String language) {
        Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        Locale sysLocale = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            sysLocale = getSystemLocale(config);
        } else {
            sysLocale = getSystemLocaleLegacy(config);
        }
        if (!language.equals("") && !sysLocale.getLanguage().equals(language)) {
            Locale locale = new Locale(language);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                setSystemLocale(config, locale);
            } else {
                setSystemLocaleLegacy(config, locale);
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
            } else {
                context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            }
        }
        return new MyContextWrapper(context);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static Locale getSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config){
        return config.locale;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public static Locale getSystemLocale(Configuration config){
        return config.getLocales().get(0);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void setSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config, Locale locale){
        config.locale = locale;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public static void setSystemLocale(Configuration config, Locale locale){
        config.setLocale(locale);
    }
}
```